# What is function 'sv' in php?

Tags: php

I'm studying a code from CMSimple 3.0 framework, with this line:

```
if (eregi('login.php', sv('PHP_SELF')))die('Access Denied');
```

So, it's suppose to display "**Access Denied**" if the char "**login.php**" is present in `sc('PHP_SELF')`.

I know that `PHP_SELF` is the name of the running script (i-e the name of the page being called). But after some research I was not able to find out the role of function **sc**.

Any idea why?

Comment: Looks like a function that is part of that framework or someone wrote it custom for that application

Comment: `sc` or `sv`, you seem to mix them up?

Comment: Also, how much research did you do? It is found in literally the first hit on a search for "CMSimple sv"

Comment: minus 1 for not checking the documentation

Comment: side note ereg is depreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation for CMSimple](http://www.cmsimple-xh.org/wiki/doku.php/core_functions) tells me:

> Returns the server variable $name, if it's set, the empty string otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The function sv in the version of CMSimple you're working on is defined on line 190 of cmsimple/cms.php (you'll notice that is the only script that does not throw a fatal error when called directly). Although the documented definition is quite brief you'll notice sv does a couple of things:

1. It creates a global variable array named $_SERVER consisting of the variables in $GLOBALS['HTTP_SERVER_VARS'], unless the array $_SERVER already exists.

The HTTP_SERVER_VARS array contains information such as headers, paths, and script locations. You will find some familiar elements in these arrays, like; PHP_SELF (which is the file name of the current executing script), REMOTE_ADDR, QUERY_STRING, and PHP_AUTH_USER. All variables that you will see sv queries for in this code base.

2. If/When $_SERVER exists it queries the array for a variable and returns it, unless the variable isn't set; then it returns ''.

The code you posted

```
if (eregi('login.php', sv('PHP_SELF')))die('Access Denied');
```

Is comparing the expression 'login.php' to the name of the script that is being executed and exiting with message 'Access Denied' if they match.